# MediaRecorder not getting initialized properly "start failed -19 which means "NO_INIT"" and "E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 0"

Tags: android

i want to record a video (with audio) from this app

but as soon as i press start recording it gives "E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -19"

i referred to this link ---> [Android MediaRecorder - "start failed: -19"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496969/android-mediarecorder-start-failed-19)  and according to them i set the supported videoSize but again i failed

and i have set the method calls according to the state diagram given on --->
"**developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html**" website

and i have set audio and video parameters as given on ---> "**developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html**" website

but nothing seems to work :(

i am testing this on my **phone Mi Redmi 2 running MIUI**

this is how UI looks like  ---> [Cam UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7hW2.jpg)

this is my code below:-

```
/*to Start recording*/
  public void startRecording() {
    Log.e(tag, "Begin StartRecording");
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
    }
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
    mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(24);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(24);
    mRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(56);
    final List<Camera.Size> mSupportedVideoSizes = getSupportedVideoSizes(camera);
    for (Camera.Size str : mSupportedVideoSizes)
        Log.e(tag, "mSupportedVideoSizes "+str.width + ":" + str.height + " ... "
                + ((float) str.width / str.height));

    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    try {
        audiofile = File.createTempFile("sound", ".mp4", dir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(tag, "external storage access error");
        return;
    }
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    mRecorder.setVideoSize(176, 144);
    mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(12);
    mRecorder.setMaxDuration(20000);
    mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w(tag, e);
    }
    try {
        mRecorder.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Recording....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        Log.w(tag, t);

    }

}


 /*To stop recording*/
public void stopRecording() {
    Log.e("", "Begin StopChange");
    if (mRecorder != null)
        try {
            mRecorder.stop();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Recording STOPPED .. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mRecorder.reset();
            mRecorder.release();

            mRecorder = null;
        }
}
```

here is the Android Manifest permissions :---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
```

Logcat :--->

```
E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -19
02-24 13:40:32.070 14892-14892/pkg.android.chintan.khetiya.cp W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
02-24 13:40:32.070 14892-14892/pkg.android.chintan.khetiya.cp W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
02-24 13:40:32.070 14892-14892/pkg.android.chintan.khetiya.cp W/System.err:     

02-25 16:40:28.952 10315-10315/pkg.android.chintan.khetiya.cp I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

> first i press the  **1) start preview button** 
>        then **2) start recording button**
>        then after making vid **3) stop recording**
>         finally **4) stop preview**

please please tell me where am i wrong ... 
any help will be appreciated thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you stop recording before seeing file size?

Comment: yes ... i have 4 buttons here 1) start preview 2) stop preview 3) start recording 4) stop recording

Comment: should i post the xml code also ?

Comment: Do you permission to write in external storage (manifest)?

Comment: yes and i have posted the manifest file also

Comment: See standard example here as it is hard to debug your problem  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Comment: yes i started this by refering to this page only but dont know why i am getting 0 byte file

Comment: should i post only the main piece of code rather than posting it as a whole ?

Comment: No. I think your configuration for the recording is invalid combination. Please follow the example exactly. After that you can modify it.

Comment: ok i will do as u said

Comment: i did as in that link .. but now getting  "E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 0"   in logcat

Comment: Are you running on your phone or emulator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339453/android-stop-recording-fail

Comment: i referred to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496969/android-mediarecorder-start-failed-19" this link .... and set the supported videosize but still getting this start failed -19 error

Comment: What I was meaning by the question is that you did something wrong with recorder. I expect you called `release()` and after that attempted to start it. Please FOLLOW the example from the standard docs EXACTLY.

Comment: I am doing exactly what is shown in the Standard Docs .... now i have posted only the start and stop recording methods code , so u can refer that to see

Comment: Please make only two buttons: start record, stop record. Click start record then click stop recording. See what is the result

Comment: nothing changed .. same start failed error :(

Comment: when i click start record after Start failed -19 error logcat shows "I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Comment: So , is there anything to suggest me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);` before `mRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am still getting that error in logcat .... i am do exactly as given on http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html  but then also am getting error

Comment: what should i do to get more support and help ?

Answer (score 0):

before setup MediaRecorder, you must invoke
`camera?.unlock()`